# Testing the fit of a 25-item one-factor model using CFA

Tags: r, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, confirmatory-factor

I'd like to test the fit of a 14-item unidimensional model using CFA. This model was formed in a previous paper that did an EFA of an originally 75-item question (thereby reducing the questions down).

To test this model using CFA, should my sample include answers from all 75 questions? Or should I include only the 25 questions that it specifies?

Below is my basic code. Thanks.

```
one.factor.model <-   'Factor1 =~ Q11 + Q29 + Q14 + Q65 + Q72 + Q52 + Q68 + Q55 + Q2 + Q5 + Q28 + Q62 + Q22 + Q75'
one.factor.fit <- cfa(one.factor.model, data= half2)
summary(one.factor.fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Where do the 25 items come from?  What do you actually want to test (and perhaps that would be easier to answer along with why do you want to test it?)

Comment: Hello, I need a unidimensional scale to run through a second analysis (DIF analysis). Upon examining the original 75 item questionnaire, I've found that it doesn't look unidimensional, although I know this is difficult to say for sure. Originally, I wanted to use PCA to reduce this down to create a more unidimensional scale, but on testing my results with CFA I have found bad fit indices. I am now turning to previous papers to try to find a more unidimensional version of the questionnaire.

Comment: BUT when I tested my own unidimensional model (which consisted of 52 items) using CFA, the sample I tested it on used included all of the 75 questions. Was I supposed to remove all of the other questions?